# Getting Invalid Character when attempting insert on Oracle Express 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I used the below create statement in Oracle Express 10g.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee( EmpNo VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
EmpName VARCHAR2(30), Department VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, Phone VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_EMPNO PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo) );
```

And then used the following insert statement.

```
Insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,EMAIL,PHONE) 
values('E100','Chuck Coordinator','Administration','chuck@colorado.edu','3-1111');
```

Why am I getting?

> "Ivalid Character"

Comment: Seems to work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e95c/1/0. If you use JDBC make 2 calls to DB without `;` at the end.

Comment: Optionally you can try `CREATE TABLE ... ) /` Slash as terminator

Comment: Are you tring it from command line or in any Oracle client. It happens generally with me when I copy/paste data from outlook/comminicator to Oracle SQL developer. Try pasting the statements ina notepad file and try again. Should work.